# How do I update the TAOCP book

Tags: ebook

I'm planning to purchase the TAOCP (The Art of Computer Programming) eBooks from the [authorized store](http://www.informit.com/taocp) as mentioned in the [website](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/%7Eknuth/taocp.html). I see that there's a up-to-date errata published for all the books, and was wondering if the publishers keep the eBooks up-to-date. I've already sent them multiple requests for information, but haven't heard back from them at all on how to update the book myself.

So,

- How can I use the errata published to keep my book up to date?

First-hand info from the owners of the book is really appreciated, and detailed steps on how to update the book myself would be amazing too. I haven't found much info on the internet regarding this.

P.S. Please add tags, I do not know anything about Latex. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Unfortunately your question is not about LaTeX at all, so it will be closed on this site. It is the case that Donald E. Knuth wrote The Art Of Computer Programming and that he also designed LaTeX (or more precisely the predecessor TeX) and that TAOCP is written using TeX (and the book is more or less the reason that TeX exists) but for buying and updating ebooks TeX or LaTeX are not involved.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about TeX, LaTeX or related technologies.

Comment: The author does use LaTeX, so I was wondering if there's a way to update the book myself

Comment: I suppose it would be conceivable that someone could get the source TeX for The Art Of Computer Programming and then use the errata to update the book.  But then the answer would boil down to "get the source TeX for the book and use the errata to update the book".